# Is there an expression similar to "I am not worried about the sky or the ground"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

There is an expression in my mother tongue - "I don't give two s*it about the sky or the ground". This expression is used to convey, "I am going down anyway. I don't have to worry about anything in the world. So, I don't mind doing something vicious".

Is there a similar expression in English?

Comment: Really, Explorer? How sure are you of that translation? Do you insist it's accurate in every sense?

Would it still mean the same in your mother tongue if we dropped *So, I don't mind doing something vicious* or would it change in any way?

For clarity, what is your mother tongue, please?

Comment: *Après moi, le déluge.*

Comment: damn the torpedoes  ...

Comment: in your question is "going down" meaning I am dying anyway?

Answer (score 1):

#### Go down with guns blazing

"With guns blazing" is used to mean "With great but reckless determination and energy" ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with_all_guns_blazing)).

Answer (score 1):

As in:

> "I am going down anyway. I don't have to worry about anything in the
>   world. So, [damn the torpedoes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/damn+the+torpedoes) and full speed ahead!".

**damn the torpedoes**

> To press on with a task or current course of action regardless of
>   apparent risks or dangers.

Answer (score 0):

Go out in a blaze of glory.  See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-blaze-of-glory